# Impact on In progress Build after configuration changes

Tags: jenkins, build

Build#1 is Inprogress from Jenkins. If I made some changes in the build part of configuration. Will it impact running Build#1 or it took all the configuration before running Build#1 so there will no impact on build#1.

Comment: the config change should only affect the future builds.